# How to add text inside the hole of the Donut Pie Chart in Flutter

Tags: charts, flutter, dart

I would like to add centered text in the middle of donut hole pie chart in Flutter like the image below :[image]

I am using `charts_flutter: ^0.6.0` and this is my code :

```dart
new charts.PieChart(
  _project.getExpensesToChartSeries(),
  animate: _animate,
  animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  selectionModels: [
    new charts.SelectionModelConfig(
      type: charts.SelectionModelType.info,
      changedListener: _onSelectionChanged,
    )
  ],
  defaultRenderer: charts.ArcRendererConfig(
    arcWidth: 25,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Stack Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) to stack content and get the result you expect, as you see below:

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      charts.PieChart(
        _project.getExpensesToChartSeries(),
        animate: true,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        selectionModels: [
          new charts.SelectionModelConfig(
            type: charts.SelectionModelType.info,
            changedListener: _onSelectionChanged,
          )
        ],
        defaultRenderer: charts.ArcRendererConfig(
          arcWidth: 25,
        ),
      ),
      Center(
        child: Text(
          "88%",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30.0,
            color: Colors.blue,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can use stack on PieChart

```
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    new charts.PieChart(
      _project.getExpensesToChartSeries(),
      animate: animate,
      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      selectionModels: [
        new charts.SelectionModelConfig(
          type: charts.SelectionModelType.info,
          changedListener: _onSelectionChanged,
      defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(arcWidth: 25),
    ),
    Center(child: Text("bla bla")),
  ],
);
```